# Accidentally created 2 UK visa applications on Gov.UK site

Tags: visas, uk

I accidentally created 2 applications. Thought I was logging in to my prior application, but was actually creating a brand new one! Both applications have the same email address.

Now I have 2 applications in draft state. I have not paid for or submitted either of them.

Is it OK to just complete one and submit it? Do I need to notify anyone that I am abandoning the other application.

Thank you.

Comment: I’m pretty certain I remember something on the website saying that incomplete applications will lapse after a while (possibly 1 month, I can’t remember for sure)

Answer (score 5):

It is perfectly alright to abandon one and complete the other. No one will hold you to it. People do so regularly.

Unfortunately I don’t have any reference saying it’s fine to have multiple incomplete applications but I have done this before and never faced any problems or questions.

IMHO no one has the time to spend scrutinising incomplete applications. The only applications that are important to them are the ones you have paid for.